# Why does my infinitely repeating selenium java code have memory leak?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, memory-leaks

I created a program that automates a job in my company. I open 3 Chrome tabs, I log into 3 different banks using the giris1ActionPerformed method. After I manually enter the OTPs that come to a phone in the company, I use the giris2ActionPerformed method to navigate to account activities pages for each bank.

After this, I use the baslaActionPerformed method to start my infinitely repeating loop, where I go to each bank one by one, find the newly arrived payments, and write them to a Google e-sheet page. After I do this, I wait 30 seconds and repeat the process.

The program works, but there is a memory leak. In a laptop with 16 GB of memory, this program lasts 5 hours. It consumes more and more RAM as time goes on. And in the end, it crashes.

I do have a thread in the basla method, but I don't think that is causing the memory leak. Because I don't keep creating new threads. I just have one thread. And inside that thread, I have an infinite loop.

I am familiar with debugging but I am not familiar with profiling a software project. Would using the profile tool of Netbeans IDE help find the memory leak?

I replaced bank passwords and google sheet IDs with "XXX" for privacy.

```
package bankaotomasyonu;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ControlPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String ziraatHandle;
    private String isHandle;
    private String garantiHandle;

    private Sheets service;
    private float satisFiyatiDakika = 0.06667F;
    private float satisFiyati = 10;
    private float alisFiyati = 14;

    private final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Bank Automation";
    private final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentialsClient1.json";
    private final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    public ControlPanel()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents()
   {

      giris1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      giris2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
      basla = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      errorScreen = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Ertürkler Banka");

      giris1.setText("Giriş 1");
      giris1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            giris1ActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      giris2.setText("Giriş 2");
      giris2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            giris2ActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      basla.setText("Başla");
      basla.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            baslaActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      jScrollPane2.setViewportView(errorScreen);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
               .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(giris1)
                  .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                  .addComponent(giris2)
                  .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                  .addComponent(basla)
                  .addGap(0, 335, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(20, 20, 20))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(giris1)
               .addComponent(basla)
               .addComponent(giris2))
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 204, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>                        

   private void giris1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                       
   {                                           
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Banka Otomasyon\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Ziraat Bankası
        driver.get("https://kurumsal.ziraatbank.com.tr/Transactions/Login/FirstLogin.aspx?customertype=crp");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_CorporateIdentityTextBox")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_CorporatePinTextBox")).sendKeys("XXX"); // 3/6 Ayda bir değişen
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_CorporateUserNameTextBox")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_CorporateLoginButton")).click();
        ziraatHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        // İş Bankası
        driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        driver.get("https://www.isbank.com.tr/TicariInternet/Transactions/Login/FirstLogin.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("CustomerNumberTextBox")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("CorporateCustomerNumberTextbox")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PinTextBox")).sendKeys("XXX"); // 3/6 Ayda bir değişen
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_t_NextButton")).click();
        isHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

        // Garanti Bankası
        driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        driver.get("https://sube.garantibbva.com.tr/isube/login/login/passwordentrycorporate-tr");
        driver.findElement(By.id("custno")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("XXX"); // 3/6 Ayda bir değişen
        driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("formSubmit")).click();
        garantiHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
   }                                      

   private void giris2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                       
   {                                           
        try
        {
            // Ziraat Bankası - Vadesiz Hesaplarım
            driver.switchTo().window(ziraatHandle);
            driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/"
                + "section[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // 5013 NOLU HESAP
            driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_GridDemandDeposit_AccountListSelector"
                + "_ctl11_ctl03_AccountName2Panel")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Hesap hareketleri
            driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_c_AccountHistoryButton")).click();

            // İş Bankası - Hesaplar
            driver.switchTo().window(isHandle);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/"
                + "div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();

            // Hesaplarım
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]"
                + "/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Hesap Hareketleri
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#MenuEntityList_tutorialElement_actions"
                + " > div:nth-child(3) > div")).click();

            // Garanti Bankası -    Hesap ve Ürün
            driver.switchTo().window(garantiHandle);
            driver.findElement(By.id("primary1")).click();

            // Hesap
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#primaryLi1 > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Dönem
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dateRangeText > div > div > div > div > div > div")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Son 7 gün
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/"
                + "div/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/"
                + "div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Görüntüle
            driver.findElement(By.id("updateSubmitButton")).click();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e);
            //e.printStackTrace();

            showError("GIRIS 2", e.toString());
        }
   }                                      

   private void baslaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                      
   {                                          
        try
        {
            final HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            service = new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(httpTransport))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            driver.switchTo().window(ziraatHandle);
                            ziraatBank();

                            driver.switchTo().window(isHandle);
                            isBank();

                            driver.switchTo().window(garantiHandle);
                            garantiBank();

                            Thread.sleep(30000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(e);
                            //e.printStackTrace();

                            showError("BASLA 2", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println(e);
            //e.printStackTrace();

            showError("BASLA 1", e.toString());
        }
   }                                     

    void ziraatBank() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, InterruptedException
    {
        List<Object> lastCustomer;
        String lastAciklama;
        String lastAmount;
        ArrayList<String> aciklamaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String aciklama;
        String amountString = "0";
        String customerName = "";
        String dekontText;
        String[] dekontTextArray;

        // Hesap Hareketlerini Güncelle 1
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1");
        boolean successfullRead = false;
        while (!successfullRead)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_InnerContentWrapperPanel > a")).click();
                successfullRead = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        successfullRead = false;

        // Hesap Hareketlerini Güncelle 2
        while (!successfullRead)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
                successfullRead = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        successfullRead = false;

        for (short row = 1; row <= 3; row++)
        {
            if ("MALTEPE E5 - 5013".equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_c_AccountBoxSelector_AccountListSelector_ctl11 "
                + "> tbody > tr:nth-child(" + row + ") > td.firstColumn > div:nth-child(1)")).getText()))
            {
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_c_AccountBoxSelector_AccountListSelector_ctl11 "
                    + "> tbody > tr:nth-child(" + row + ") > td.firstColumn > div:nth-child(1)")).click();
                break;
            }
        }

        while (!successfullRead)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1");
                successfullRead = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        // Find which row is the last customer
        lastCustomer = readLastCustomer("A1:B1");
        lastAciklama = lastCustomer.get(0).toString();
        lastAmount = lastCustomer.get(1).toString();
        short rowNumber = 0;

        do
        {
            rowNumber++;
            successfullRead = false;
            while (!successfullRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    aciklamaList.add(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_c_GridAccountHistoryList"
                        + " > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td.description")).getText());
                    amountString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/"
                        + "div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/"
                        + "table/tbody/tr[" + rowNumber + "]/td[4]")).getText();
                    successfullRead = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        } while (!((lastAciklama.equals(aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1))) && (lastAmount.equals(amountString))));

        // If last row is the last customer, quit
        if (rowNumber != 1)
        {
            // Process new customers (the ones after the last customer)
            do
            {
                rowNumber--;

                aciklama = aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1);

                // Date
                String date = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_c_GridAccountHistoryList >"
                    + " tbody > tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td.firstColumn.nowrap.date")).
                    getText().replace("/", ".");

                // Amount
                amountString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/"
                    + "div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/"
                    + "table/tbody/tr[" + rowNumber + "]/td[4]")).getText();
                if (amountString.startsWith("-"))
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A1:B1", aciklama, amountString);
                    continue;
                }
                float amount = Float.parseFloat(amountString.replace(".", "").
                    replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""));

                // Dekontu aç
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctl00_c_GridAccountHistoryList > tbody >"
                    + " tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td:nth-child(6) > a")).click();

                // Dekont isim
                driver.switchTo().frame("GenericCustomModalFrame");
                driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
                dekontText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]"
                    + "/div/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/"
                    + "table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")).getText();

                // Dekontu kapat
                Thread.sleep(250);
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/button")).click();

                // Customer name
                if (dekontText.contains("Borçlu Adı Soyadı : ")) // Mobil havale
                    customerName = dekontText.split("Borçlu Adı Soyadı : ")[1].split("\n")[0];
                else if (dekontText.contains("Gönd: ")) // Fast
                {
                    dekontTextArray = dekontText.split("Gönd: ");

                    // Aciklamada fast varsa VE ilk satır alt cizgi değilse bu kod çalışacak
                    if (aciklama.contains("FAST") && !dekontText.startsWith("_") && !dekontText.startsWith("."))
                        customerName = dekontTextArray[1].split(dekontText.split("\n")[0])[0];
                    // 1- fast yoksa. 2- fast varsa VE ilk satır alt çizgiyse. 
                    else
                    {
                        dekontTextArray = dekontTextArray[1].split(" ");
                        for (byte counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++)
                            if (Character.isUpperCase(dekontTextArray[counter].charAt(0)))
                                customerName += dekontTextArray[counter] + " ";
                    }

                    customerName = customerName.trim().toUpperCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("TR"));
                }
                else if (dekontText.contains("Gönderen : ")) // Referanslı Gelen Havale
                    customerName = dekontText.split("Gönderen : ")[1].split("\n")[0]; // Buranın toUpperCase e ihtiyacı varsa, toUpperCase i assagı at.
                else
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A1:B1", aciklama, amountString);
                    showError("ZİRAAT BANKASI", aciklama);
                    continue;
                }

                // Google Sheets
                appendToGoogleSheets(date, amount, customerName, "ZİRAAT BANKASI");

                // Last customer text file
                writeLastCustomer("A1:B1", aciklama, amountString);

                customerName = "";
            } while (rowNumber > 1);
        }

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }

    void isBank() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        List<Object> lastCustomer;
        String lastAciklama;
        String lastAmount;
        ArrayList<String> aciklamaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String aciklama;
        String amountString = "0";
        String customerName = "";

        // Hesap Hareketlerini Güncelle
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" #UpdateActivitiesSubMenu_tutorialElement "
            + "> div.sub-menu-item-text")).click();

        // Find which row is the last customer
        lastCustomer = readLastCustomer("A2:B2");
        lastAciklama = lastCustomer.get(0).toString();
        lastAmount = lastCustomer.get(1).toString();
        short rowNumber = 0;

        do
        {
            rowNumber++;
            boolean successfullRead = false;
            while (!successfullRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    aciklamaList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/"
                        + "div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/"
                        + "div[" + rowNumber + "]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div")).getText());
                    amountString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/"
                        + "div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div["
                        + rowNumber + "]/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]")).getText().replace(" ", "");
                    successfullRead = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        } while (!((lastAciklama.equals(aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1))) && (lastAmount.equals(amountString))));

        // If last row is the last customer, quit
        if (rowNumber != 1)
        {
            // Process new customers (the ones after the last customer)
            do
            {
                rowNumber--;

                aciklama = aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1);

                // Date
                String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/"
                    + "div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[" + rowNumber
                    + "]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]")).getText().replace("/", ".");

                // Amount
                amountString = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/"
                    + "div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div["
                    + rowNumber + "]/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]")).getText().replace(" ", "");
                if (amountString.startsWith("-") || aciklama.contains("VODAFONE"))
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A2:B2", aciklama, amountString);
                    continue;
                }
                float amount = Float.parseFloat(amountString.substring(1).replace(",", ""));

                // Customer Name
                if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/"
                    + "div[1]/div[3]/div/div[9]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[" + rowNumber
                    + "]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div")).getText().equals("Bankamatik"))
                {
                    String[] arrOfAciklama = aciklama.split(" ");
                    if (arrOfAciklama.length > 1 & arrOfAciklama.length < 4)
                        customerName = (arrOfAciklama.length == 2) ? arrOfAciklama[1] + " "
                            + arrOfAciklama[0] : arrOfAciklama[1] + arrOfAciklama[2] + arrOfAciklama[0];
                    else
                    {
                        writeLastCustomer("A2:B2", aciklama, amountString);
                        showError("İŞ BANKASI", aciklama);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else if (aciklama.contains("tarafından"))
                {
                    customerName = aciklama.split("tarafından", 2)[0].trim();
                }
                else if (aciklama.contains("*"))
                {
                    if (Character.isDigit(aciklama.split("\\*")[1].charAt(0)))
                        customerName = aciklama.split("\\*")[0];
                    else
                        customerName = aciklama.split("\\*")[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A2:B2", aciklama, amountString);
                    showError("İŞ BANKASI", aciklama);
                    continue;
                }

                customerName = customerName.toUpperCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("TR"));

                // Google Sheets
                appendToGoogleSheets(date, amount, customerName, "İŞ BANKASI");

                // Save last customer
                writeLastCustomer("A2:B2", aciklama, amountString);

            } while (rowNumber > 1);
        }
    }

    void garantiBank() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, InterruptedException
    {
        List<Object> lastCustomer;
        String lastAciklama;
        String lastAmount;
        ArrayList<String> aciklamaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String aciklama;
        String amountString = "0";
        String customerName = "";
        String dekontText;

        // Görüntüle
        driver.findElement(By.id("updateSubmitButton")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);

        // Find which row is the last customer
        lastCustomer = readLastCustomer("A3:B3");
        lastAciklama = lastCustomer.get(0).toString();
        lastAmount = lastCustomer.get(1).toString();
        short rowNumber = 0;

        do
        {
            rowNumber++;
            boolean successfullRead = false;
            while (!successfullRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    aciklamaList.add(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myAccountActivitiesGrid > tbody > tr:nth-child("
                        + rowNumber + ") > td.customHoverEnabled > div > div:nth-child(1)")).getText());
                    amountString = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myAccountActivitiesGrid > "
                        + "tbody > tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td:nth-child(4) > div")).getText();
                    successfullRead = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        } while (!((lastAciklama.equals(aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1))) && (lastAmount.equals(amountString))));

        // If last row is the last customer, quit
        if (rowNumber != 1)
        {
            // Process new customers (the ones after the last customer)
            do
            {
                rowNumber--;

                aciklama = aciklamaList.get(rowNumber - 1);

                // Amount
                amountString = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myAccountActivitiesGrid > "
                    + "tbody > tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td:nth-child(4) > div")).getText();
                if (amountString.startsWith("-") || aciklama.startsWith("PK"))
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A3:B3", aciklama, amountString);
                    continue;
                }
                float amount = Float.parseFloat(amountString.substring(1).
                    replace(".", "").replace(",", ".").replace(" TL", ""));

                // Dekontu aç
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myAccountActivitiesGrid > tbody > "
                    + "tr:nth-child(" + rowNumber + ") > td:nth-child(3) > a")).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                // Dekont date
                String date = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" #receiptScroll " // you can try putting this into an infinite loop like ziraat guncelleme
                    + "> div > table.receiptContainerTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) "
                    + "> td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > pre")).
                    getText().split("İŞLEM TARİHİ     : ")[1].split("\n")[0].trim().
                    replace("/", "."); // substring(1).trim().replace("/", ".");

                // Dekont isim
                dekontText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/"
                    + "div[2]/form/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/pre")).getText();

                // Dekontu kapat
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a")).click();

                // Customer name                
                if (dekontText.contains("BORÇLU HESAP")) // hesaptan hesaba havale
                    customerName = dekontText.split("\n")[3].substring(42).trim();
                // "gelen fast", "gelen eft", "kredi kartindan hesaba havale", "hesaba havale (kasadan)" (atm)
                else if (dekontText.contains("GÖNDEREN  "))
                {
                    customerName = dekontText.split("GÖNDEREN  ")[1].split("\n")[0].trim().substring(2);
                    //customerName = dekontText.split("\n")[1].substring(21).trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    writeLastCustomer("A3:B3", aciklama, amountString);
                    showError("GARANTİ BANKASI", aciklama);
                    continue;
                }

                // Google Sheets
                appendToGoogleSheets(date, amount, customerName, "GARANTİ BANKASI");

                // Last customer text file
                writeLastCustomer("A3:B3", aciklama, amountString);

            } while (rowNumber > 1);
        }
    }

    void appendToGoogleSheets(String date, float amount, String customerName, String bankName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        String spreadsheetId = "XXX"; //XXX
        String range = "A:K";
        List<List<Object>> newValues = new ArrayList<>();

        float dakika = Math.round(amount / satisFiyatiDakika);
        float adet = Math.round((amount / satisFiyati) * 100.0F) / 100.0F;
        float maliyet = Math.round((adet * alisFiyati) * 100.0F) / 100.0F;
        float fark = Math.round((amount - maliyet) * 100.0F) / 100.0F;

        newValues.add(Arrays.asList(date, amount, dakika, adet, maliyet, fark,
            "", "", customerName, bankName, "X+"));

        // Append the new data starting from the first empty row in column A
        ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange().setValues(newValues);

        service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
            .setValueInputOption("RAW").execute();
    }

    List readLastCustomer(String range) throws IOException
    {
        String spreadsheetId = "XXX";
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        return values.get(0);
    }

    void writeLastCustomer(String range, String aciklama, String amount) throws IOException
    {
        String spreadsheetId = "XXX";

        ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange().setValues(Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList((Object) aciklama, (Object) amount)));

        service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
            .setValueInputOption("RAW").execute();
    }

    void showError(String banka, String aciklama)
    {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        errorScreen.setText(errorScreen.getText() + banka + " " + aciklama + "\n\n");
    }

    private Credential getCredentials(final HttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream credentialsStream = ControlPanel.class
            .getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(credentialsStream));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline").build();

        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build())
            .authorize("user");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try
        {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
            {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
                {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        catch (InstantiationException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ControlPanel.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new ControlPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   private javax.swing.JButton basla;
   private javax.swing.JTextPane errorScreen;
   private javax.swing.JButton giris1;
   private javax.swing.JButton giris2;
   private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Capture a head dump and use a heap dump analysis tool like eclipse MAT to find what is using the memory.

Comment: Just some general feedback, your code is a complete mess! I would honestly say you need to re-write all of it with a re-thought-out design. (Also in future perhaps state the Java version you have built an application in as the answers might differ based on your Java version.

Comment: You should not expect people here to review a big chunk of code and find some specific line of an issue that happens at execution time. Capture heap dumps at execution time when memory is high and analyze them first.

Comment: that first do/while loop looks bad to me...   sort of a mix of do-while and while... and probably infinite.  Then a while with no body afterwards...  hard to follow.  giris1ActionPerformed has some problems with switchTo calls...  but the main cause might be just what you said.. .infinitely repeating and some variable is always getting larger.  Not a leak... but maybe you should poke a hole in it...

Comment: probably need to dispose of things after you write the values.